# Composer cannot be used globally

Tags: php, composer-php, macbookpro-touch-bar

[terminal picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6yrE.png)

I just got my macbook pro today i followed a tutorial how to install composer globally
I installed first mamp as local server then installed composer which works fine while i am in root 
directory on mac,then i created a bash profile and added a path

export PATH=" /.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"

like this after this i created an alias to enter htdocs in MAMP and when i test it inside docs it says composer not found.

I appreciate everyone who will help me figure this one out.

I tried all methods from below,whenever i try to move it it says rename composer.phar to /usr/local/bin/composer/: No such directory..

Comment: Run this in your terminal `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and type 
`nano ~/.bash_profile`

Add the following

`alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar"`

*Finally run:*

`source ~/.bash_profile`

Check this out here: https://duvien.com/blog/installing-composer-mac-osx

Comment: Could not open in input file : usr/local/bin/composer.phar

Comment: Replace the path to your composer path.

Comment: How do i do that? Sorry for asking this basic questions but i am newbiie :)

Comment: alias composer="php add_path_to_composer_here". It should have worked using the path that I added working for me on a Mac

Comment: i added the path as you told me but stilli i get this error

Comment: i think it's in Users/user

Comment: So now to delete the composer and try again ? also when i am in the root folder i see that composer is installed but when i am into htdocs says not found which mean that its not installed globally.